# How to plot a pie chart with the first wedge on top, in Python? [matplotlib]

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

How can a pie chart be drawn with Matplotlib with a first wedge that starts at noon (i.e. on the top of the pie)?  The default is for `pyplot.pie()` to place the first edge at three o'clock, and it would be great to be able to customize this.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220933/plotting-a-pie-chart-in-matplotlib-at-a-specific-angle-with-the-fracs-on-the-wed][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220933/plotting-a-pie-chart-in-matplotlib-at-a-specific-angle-with-the-fracs-on-the-wed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just because this came up in a Google search for me, I'll add that in the meantime, matplotlib has included just this as an additional argument to the `pie` function.

Now, one can call `plt.pie(data, startangle=90)` to have the first wedge start at noon.

[PyPlot documentation on this](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pie)

Answer (score 6):

It's a bit of a hack, but you can do something like this...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D
import numpy as np

x = [5, 20, 10, 10]
labels=['cliffs', 'frogs', 'stumps', 'old men on tractors']

plt.figure()
plt.suptitle("Things I narrowly missed while learning to drive")
wedges, labels = plt.pie(x, labels=labels)
plt.axis('equal')

starting_angle = 90
rotation = Affine2D().rotate(np.radians(starting_angle))

for wedge, label in zip(wedges, labels):
    label.set_position(rotation.transform(label.get_position()))
    if label._x > 0:
        label.set_horizontalalignment('left')
    else:
        label.set_horizontalalignment('right')

    wedge._path = wedge._path.transformed(rotation)

plt.show()
```

[image: Example Pie Plot]

Comment: +1!  This is sufficiently long for such a simple need that I wish that `pie()` had an additional `start_angle` parameter.

Comment: @EOL - I agree, it seems awfully complicated for what should be a fairly common and simple need... Maybe an enhancement request for a `start_angle` parameter is a good idea?  I can't imagine that you're the only person who has ever needed `pie()` to start at a different angle...