# Plotting a pie-chart in matplotlib at a specific angle with the fracs on the wedges

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart, wedge

I am plotting a piechart with matplotlib using the following code:

```
ax = axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.6, 0.6])
labels = 'Twice Daily', 'Daily', '3-4 times per week', 'Once per week','Occasionally'
fracs = [20,50,10,10,10]

explode=(0, 0, 0, 0,0.1)
patches, texts, autotexts = ax.pie(fracs, labels=labels, explode = explode,         
                             autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow =True)
proptease = fm.FontProperties()
proptease.set_size('xx-small')
setp(autotexts, fontproperties=proptease)
setp(texts, fontproperties=proptease)
rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 7.0
savefig("pie1")
```

This produces the following piechart. 
[image: PieChart 1]

However, I want to start the pie-chart with the first wedge on top, the only solution I could find for this was using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816809/how-to-plot-a-pie-chart-with-the-first-wedge-on-top-in-python-matplotlib)

However on using this as below,

```
from pylab import *
from matplotlib import font_manager as fm
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D
from matplotlib.patches import Circle, Wedge, Polygon
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

labels = 'Twice Daily', 'Daily', '3-4 times per week', 'Once per week','Occasionally'
fracs = [20,50,10,10,10]

 wedges, plt_labels = ax.pie(fracs, labels=labels)
 ax.axis('equal')

 starting_angle = 90
 rotation = Affine2D().rotate(np.radians(starting_angle))

for wedge, label in zip(wedges, plt_labels):
  label.set_position(rotation.transform(label.get_position()))
  if label._x > 0:
    label.set_horizontalalignment('left')
  else:
    label.set_horizontalalignment('right')

  wedge._path = wedge._path.transformed(rotation)

plt.savefig("pie2")
```

This produces the following pie chart

[image]

However, this does not print the fracs on the wedges as in the earlier pie chart. I have tried a few different things, but I am not able to preserve the fracs. How can I start the first wedge at noon and display the fracs on the wedges as well??

Answer (score 2):

Ordinarily I wouldn't recommend changing the source of a tool, but it's hacky to fix this outside and easy inside.  So here's what I'd do if you needed this to work Right Now(tm), and sometimes you do..

In the file `matplotlib/axes.py`, change the declaration of the pie function to

```
def pie(self, x, explode=None, labels=None, colors=None,
        autopct=None, pctdistance=0.6, shadow=False,
        labeldistance=1.1, start_angle=None):
```

i.e. simply add `start_angle=None` to the end of the arguments.

Then add the five lines bracketed by "# addition".

```
    for frac, label, expl in cbook.safezip(x,labels, explode):
        x, y = center
        theta2 = theta1 + frac
        thetam = 2*math.pi*0.5*(theta1+theta2)

        # addition begins here
        if start_angle is not None and i == 0:
            dtheta = (thetam - start_angle)/(2*math.pi)
            theta1 -= dtheta
            theta2 -= dtheta
            thetam = start_angle
        # addition ends here

        x += expl*math.cos(thetam)
        y += expl*math.sin(thetam)
```

Then if start_angle is None, nothing happens, but if start_angle has a value, then that's the location that the first slice (in this case the 20%) is centred on.  For example,

```
patches, texts, autotexts = ax.pie(fracs, labels=labels, explode = explode,         
                             autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow =True, start_angle=0.75*pi)
```

produces

[image]

Note that in general you should avoid doing this, patching the source I mean, but there are times in the past when I've been on deadline and simply wanted something Now(tm), so there you go..